# Create schedule task via Invoke-Expression Powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to create schedule task via Invoke-Expression like below. I am getting error message.

```
$command = @'
    cmd.exe /C C:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe /create /f /tn "Restart Computer" /tr "shutdown.exe -r -t 60 -f" /sc once /st "01:59" /sd "12/30/2021" /ru "SYSTEM" /s "localhost" /RL "HIGHEST" /v1 /z
    '@
    Invoke-Expression -Command:$command
```

Here is my error message :

```
cmd.exe : ERROR: The network path was not found.
At line:1 char:1
+ cmd.exe /C C:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe /create /f /tn "Restart C ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (ERROR: The network path was not found.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

Comment: I recommend you to use the related ScheduleTask cmdlets within PowerShell, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/?view=windowsserver2022-ps

Comment: Looks like your inserted `"localhost"` is wrong. Leave that out if you want to have it shut down the local computer or use switch `\m` to specify the target computer if it is a remote machine. See [Shitdown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/shutdown)

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$command = 'cmd.exe /C C:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe /create /f /tn "Restart Computer" /tr "shutdown.exe -r -t 60 -f" /sc once /st "01:59" /sd "12/30/2021" /ru "SYSTEM" /s "localhost" /RL "HIGHEST" /v1 /z'
Invoke-Expression -Command:$command
```

[image: Output]

Comment: still same issue

Comment: did you started powershell as administrator?, you need an elevated privilege to execute this command successfully.

Comment: lilke you said I have tried it

Comment: did you managed to create the Scheduled task?, please share the error if you still have a problem, ii not please mark the Answer as Answer.

Comment: I am getting same error message. cmd.exe : ERROR: The network path was not found.
At line:1 char:1
+ cmd.exe /C C:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe /create /f /tn "Restart C ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (ERROR: The network path was not found.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Comment: i cannot reproduce your error, but i updated the post with a screenshot from my powershell terminal, please check it if you are typing something different.